# how to find all documents with only looking at first letter of the values in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

i want to find all documents by its first letter.

the case is when i query in mysql then i could do `WHERE Stores LIKE 'a%'`

```
the result would be all data with the first letter a.
```

the question are :

- How to make the same `query` using `mongoose`?
- how about `case-sensitive` `eg: (a,A)`. it would be the same query or not?
- is it necessary to create `lowercase_field` for this case ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a [$regex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) operator for that purpose, the query will look like:

```
Model.find({"name": {$regex: /^a/, $options: 'i'}}).exec(callback);
```

and it could be simplified to:

```
Model.find({"name": /^a/i}}).exec(callback);
```

In case you need to pass a variable in the query:

```
var char = 'a';
Model.find({"name": {$regex: '^' + char, $options: 'i'}}).exec(callback);
```

Comment: im newbie in regex, how to pass variable inside it? 

`$regex: /^variable/`

Comment: work like this in my case: Model.find({"name": {$regex: '^' + char, $options: 'i'}}).exec(callback);